# How to remove the blue icon in a SP site?

Tags: office-365

How can I remove the blue icon that appears when you deploy a hosted app?
I am using Office 365.
Thx!

[image]

Comment: Do you actually want to remove it completely and thus shift the app title (e.g. SharepointApp2) to the left? Or do you want to change it?

Comment: I just want to remove the icon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide using the css:

```
#siteIcon{   
    display:none; 
}
```